# delete empty entries tuple List String

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have a Tuple List with 5 String values. This list contains about 250 entries with many empty entries.
How to delete these empty entries?

```
 var program_list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string>>();
 program_list.Add(Tuple.Create(program_name_String, publisher_name_String, program_version_String, install_location_String, uninstall_location_String));
```

I know how to delete these empty entries with a single String List. But this code won't work on Tuple List anymore.

```
program_names = program_names.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Distinct().ToList();
program_names = program_names.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Distinct().ToList();
program_names.Sort();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which entries *exactly* do you want to filter out? Those where all 5 strings are empty? Those where at least one of the five strings is empty? Those where the first of the five strings (the program name) is empty? (Hint: The last one is easiest to implement. Do you want to give it a try before we spoil this puzzle for you?)

Comment: IMHO, create a new class and put them in a `List<Apps>`... your work is much easier at this point. Also, it seems before adding them to the list, why not check the strings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using a class rather than a tuple.  Also you can still use it the same way you were using it for a string list.  You just need to let it know to go deeper. Replace s with s.Item1 and you are set.

```
program_names = program_names.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Item1)).Distinct().ToList();
```

but I suggest this:

```
    public class myProgramClass
    {
        public string name, publisher_name, version, install_location, uninstall_location;
    }

    List<myProgramClass> program_list = new List<myProgramClass>();

    myProgramClass new_entry = new myProgramClass() { name = "Name", publisher_name = "pub Name", version = "1.02", install_location = "dir", uninstall_location = "" };
    program_list.Add(new_entry);

    program_list = program_list.Where(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.name)).Distinct().ToList();
```